# Transmit the contents of a canvas tag to a php script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending images from Canvas elements using Ajax and PHP $_FILES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292689/sending-images-from-canvas-elements-using-ajax-and-php-files)

I created an application where users can edit in real time the content of a canvas tag.
It then retrieves the contents of the tag like this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var imgca  = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Now I am looking for a way to pass the contents of the `imgca` variable to a PHP script that the user can then be sent by e-mail.

Does anyone has any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending images from Canvas elements using Ajax and PHP $\_FILES](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292689/sending-images-from-canvas-elements-using-ajax-and-php-files) and possible others like [clear Canvas and save Canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693221/clear-canvas-and-save-canvas)

Answer (score 0):

You could try having a form with a hidden input element that posts to a php script and use your imgca to set the value of this hidden input element, so something likes this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var imgca  = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

document.getElementById("hiddenElement").value = imgca;
document.getElementById("myHiddenForm").submit();
```

with html:

```
<form id="myHiddenForm" action="somescript.php" method="post" style="display:none;">
    <input type="hidden" id="hiddenElement" value="" />
</form>
```