# How to make qr codes generated by steeve:jquery-qrcode package downloadable

Tags: jquery, download, qr-code

I have a Meteor project where each user has a profile page and they have their own qr code linking to that page.  I would like to make the qr code that I've generated for them using steeve:jquery-qrcode downloadable in either a jpg or png format (both if possible).

How would I accomplish this?  (i.e. make it downloadable from the client)

At the moment I just display the qr code on the user's page using the following code on the page:

```
<template name="profile">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    Username:   {{username}}<br />
    {{#with profile}}
        Profile name: {{firstName}} {{lastName}}
    {{/with}}
    <div id="qrblock"></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And here's the JS on the client:

```
Template.profile.onRendered(function () {
  console.log(this.data.qrUrl);
  $('#qrblock').qrcode({text: this.data.profile.qrUrl});
});
```

Edit:  Would this some be easier to achieve by using an `img` element instead of a `div` element?

Comment: can you post your working code, or post your link?

Comment: [kapital.meteor.com](http://kapital.meteor.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I referenced following link: [Download a Html5 canvas element as an image with the file extension with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915199/download-a-html5-canvas-element-as-an-image-with-the-file-extension-with-javascr)

```
<a id="downloadImgLink" onclick="$('#downloadImgLink').attr('href', $('#qrblock canvas')[0].toDataURL());" download="MyImage.png" href="#" target="_blank">Download Drawing</a>
```

Place this link anywhere on your view. It should download an image as png file.

As for browser compatibility issue, IE and Safari doesn't support download attribute yet. Here is a link about [download attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp).

Comment: Is there a way to make this work for jpg and pdf as well?  Because I've tried changing the name and that doesn't work...

Comment: Actually, changing only download filename won't work. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

It says toDataURL() can have two parameters:toDataURL(type, encoderOptions);