# How save image from canvas tag to php server?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, html

I have a javascript code like this

```
var testCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas-1');
var canvasData = testCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("POST",'http://www.domain.com/imgsave.php',true);
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'canvas/upload');
ajax.send("canvasData"+canvasData );
```

My php code is like this

```
if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]))
{
    // Get the data
    $imageData=$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];

    $filteredData=substr($imageData, strpos($imageData, ",")+1);

    $unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);
    $fp = fopen( 'test.png', 'wb' );
    fwrite( $fp, $unencodedData);
    fclose( $fp );
        echo "saved";
}
  else{

  echo "no raw data";
  }
```

When executing this code i got a zero size png file image? Whats the problem with my code?

Comment: And of course you checked that `$unencodedData` is not empty, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to do this recently myself.

First I put my canvasData into a hidden field and posted it to my PHP page.

It comes back in this format: `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0......`

You need to split the data up first, as this: `data:image/png;base64,` is header information. The rest is the encoded data.

```
$rawData = $_POST['imageData'];
$filteredData = explode(',', $rawData);

$unencoded = base64_decode($filteredData[1]);
```

I then create the image on my server:

```
//Create the image 
$fp = fopen('sigs/test1.png', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $unencoded);
fclose($fp);
```

And then read it to do whatever I want with it.

```
$file_name = 'test1.png';
$file_size = strlen($filteredData[1])/1024; //This may be wrong, doesn't seem to break for me though.


$fh = fopen('sigs/test1.png', 'r');
$content = fread($fh, $file_size);
$content = base64_encode($content);
fclose($fh);
```

I'm more than sure there is a much more elegant solution to this, but this has been working for me!

Check this for more info (possibly): [My own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751555/how-can-i-save-a-dynamically-generated-image-to-my-database)

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I do save image from canvas via ajax. I use jQuery on client side

```
 jQuery.ajax({
     url: 'save.php',
     type: 'POST',
     data: {
         data: c.toDataURL('image/png')
     },
     complete: function(data, status)
     {
         if(status=='success')
         {
            alert('saved!');
         }
         alert('Error has been occurred');
     }

 });
```

php:

```
    $based64Image=substr($_POST['data'], strpos($_POST['data'], ',')+1);

    $image = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($based64Image));

    $fileName='';
    if($image != false)
    {
        $fileName=time().'.png';
        if(!imagepng($image, $fileName))
        {
//          fail;
        }
    }
    else
    {
//          fail;
    }
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

According to a [comment in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php), to get the HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, you need to do something like this:

```
<?php $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); ?>
```

The manual says this about the wrappers such as `php://input`:

> In the case of POST requests, it is preferable to use php://input
>   instead of $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA as it does not depend on special
>   php.ini directives.